# Unable to git clone to disk mouted as SFTP drive

Tags: windows, git

I'm under Win7 and trying to `git clone` rep to my `Z:` disk.
Disk `Z:` is mouted via SFTP (connecting to local FreeBSD server) using `SFTP Net Drive Free` utility.

When I'm trying to `git clone` to my local `C:` disk - everything works fine, but when I'm trying to `git clone` to disk `Z:` git reports about errors:

```
cd z:
$ git clone git@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:rep.git
Cloning into 'rep'...
error: could not commit config file z:/rep/.git/config
error: could not commit config file z:/rep/.git/config
error: could not commit config file z:/rep/.git/config
error: could not commit config file z:/rep/.git/config
error: could not commit config file z:/rep/.git/config
error: could not commit config file z:/rep/.git/config
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I've tried to git clone some public repo from github:

```
$ cd c:
$ git clone https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis.git
Cloning into 'phpredis'...
remote: Counting objects: 3703, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1578/1578), done.
remote: Total 3703 (delta 2286), reused 3512 (delta 2114)
Receiving objects: 100% (3703/3703), 1.43 MiB | 264.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2286/2286), done.
Checking connectivity... done
```

but the same error with `Z:`

```
$ cd z:
$ git clone https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis.git
Cloning into 'phpredis'...
error: could not commit config file z:/phpredis/.git/config
error: could not commit config file z:/phpredis/.git/config
error: could not commit config file z:/phpredis/.git/config
error: could not commit config file z:/phpredis/.git/config
error: could not commit config file z:/phpredis/.git/config
error: could not commit config file z:/phpredis/.git/config
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but you do have write permissions for the mounted drive, right? I run a very similar setup, but with ExpanDrive instead of the utility you mentioned.

Comment: @ChrisS, thank you for comment. Yes, I have write perms. I can `cd z:; mkdir blablabla` using `git-bash`.

Comment: @ChrisS, is `git clone` from `git-bash` works ok with Expandrive?

Comment: Yep - works fine for me, though a touch slow across the Internet. Sorry that took a minute to install git-bash. I usually use TortiseGit and TortiseHG in Windows.

Comment: @ChrisS, thank you for testing for me. I'm trying Expandrive right now, but it seems not working for me - unable to mount SFTP. Trying to figure out why right now!

Comment: @ChrisS, sorry for delay. With Expandrive everything works ok.

Comment: I'm on windows 10 and using SFTP drive. I have the same problem and in addition cannot `git init` on the mapped drive. In both cases I get the error: `error: could not write config file Z:/src/test/.git/config: Input/output error
fatal: could not set 'core.filemode' to 'false'`

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me.  To fix it, I deleted c:.gitconfig, and when I ran `git clone <project>` .. it worked okay.